# Users are not able to download app via firebase App Distribution – flutter

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I'm starting to distribute my app to some testers via Firebase Distribution (IOS)

What I did: opened project in Xcode -> archive -> distribute app -> Ad Hoc -> .ipa file
dragged .ipa file to the informed place.

First, I added my email, followed the steps and was able to download the app.

But, now I'm not being able. When the users accepts the invite and download the profile in "general", the app download isn't available. They get the message:

> Registered device! The developer now needs to update their app to run on the device. You will receive an email when the app is available for testing.

The, I get an email with a UDID from each user.

I don't have any idea what to do.

Did I do something wrong? its it possible to the user automatically have the app available for download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did nothing wrong, this is how Firebase works. As long as you're on iOS, it is not possible to have the app automatically available. (If it were possible, you could use Firebase instead of the App Store, and Apple wants to avoid that).

**You need to do the following:**

1. Go to Apple's developer site and add the device(s) to your test devices list. It should be here: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list and you'll need to sign it with your Apple ID. If you are part of multiple developer teams, make sure you select the right one in the top right of the screen.
2. Add those new device(s) to the Ad Hoc profile that you are using for building this device. If you check the list here https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list there should be a profile with the ID of your app
3. Build the app again with your updated profile. How you do this will depend on your build process
4. Upload the new build to firebase. (It is possible to do this automatically if you are using a tool like Fastlane). Make sure your tester has access to the new build: this can be done in the Firebase UI by adding testers or groups to the build. (It can also be done automatically if you are uploading automatically)
5. Your tester should receive an email about the new build. When they check the *App Distribution* app that they have installed, they will see a list of versions with the newest one available to download

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).